# Mostrar un valor por defecto al traer una consulta sin resultados

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta, la cual compara los datos de una tabla con otra.
Ahora resulta que de la consulta A es posible que no arroje registros, entonces en el WHERE V.Semana between A.Semana and S.Semana si A.Semana no contiene nada, necesito poner el numero 27.
Alguna idea?.
Gracias
Saludos

```
IdUser  Codigo  Cantidad
112 02158   225
112 02422   25
112 03173   80
112 03353   550
112 03739   701
```

Lo siguiente es mi codigo:

```
    select V.IdUser, V.Codigo, sum(V.Cantidad) as Cantidad

    FROM (select max(S.Semana) as Semana, V.IdUser, V.Codigo from SVisitas V

    left join Calendario S ON V.Fecha between S.Inicio and S.Fin 

    group by V.IdUser, V.Codigo)A 

    left join (select * from(select IdUser,Codigo,Temporada,SUM(Cantidad) 
as Cantidad,Semana from SCantidadesP group by IdUser,Codigo,Temporada,Cantidad,Semana)V
 where V.Cantidad <> 0)V on A.IdUser=V.IdUser and A.Codigo=V.Codigo 

    left join (Select * from Calendario where Getdate() between Inicio and
 Fin)S on V.Temporada=S.Temporada WHERE V.Semana between A.Semana and 
S.Semana 
    group by V.IdUser,V.Codigo
```

Estas son mis tablas

```
SVisitas 
IdUser int
Codigo varchar(5)
Fecha datetime

Calendario 
Semana int
Inicio datetime
Fin datetime
Temporada int

SCantidadesP
IdUser int
Codigo varchar(5)
Cantidad int
Semana int
Temporada int
```

Aqui dejo un ejemplo de los datos que almacenan mis tablas, lo que necesito es ver todos los registros de mi tabla SCantidadesP aunque los codigos no se encuentren en la tabla SVisitas

```
SVisitas 
IdUser Codigo   Fecha
112    02158    2019-11-12
112   02422    2019-12-03

Calendario 
Temporada Semana    Inicio       Fin
1920          45    2019-11-04   2019-11-10  
1920          46    2019-11-11   2019-11-17  
1920          47    2019-11-18   2019-11-24  
1920          48    2019-11-25   2019-12-01  
1920          49    2019-12-02   2019-12-08  
1920          50    2019-12-09   2019-12-15  
1920          51    2019-12-16   2019-12-22  
1920          52    2019-12-23   2019-12-29  

SCantidadesP
IdUser Codigo Cantidad Semana Temporada 
112    02158   234       50    1920
112    02458   1000      45    1920
112    02565   654       45    1920
112    02157   287       51    1920
112    02159   098       49    1920
```

Comment: Me parece que usar : select coalesce (max(S.Semana),27) as Semana, V.IdUser, V.Codigo , en el select de tu subquery  A, resuelve esto, esto con base a lo que entendí en tus datos, ayudaría mas que agregaras los create table mas un insert con una muestra de datos.

Comment: Para empezar, no tienes la columna `V.Semana` para el último WHERE.

Comment: @EmersonRios Gracias por su aporte, probé con coalesce  pero no funciona

Comment: @LuisCazares hola a que se refiere con que no tengo V.Semana en el ultimo where?

Comment: Si pudieras poner unos datos para las tablas de muestra para tratar de replicar tu error.

Comment: Creo que este te puede ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131039/8933039 dale un vistazo...

Comment: Hola amigo inserte los datos que me muestres y si me devuelve resultados, cual es el error que tienes o que es lo que pasa o que es lo que esperas recibir

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Hola, mira de la primer consulta arroja un valor semana si los codigos de la tabla SCantidadesP tambien existen en SVisitas entonces semana si ienevalor, si no existen ahi debe arrojar el numero 27 para el valor Semana, me explico?

Comment: El código de ejemplo no compila porque la referencia a V.Semana es inválida, así como la columna Cod_Prod. Los datos de prueba no cuadran con los resultados esperados y las filas de visitas no cuadran con las filas de cantidades puesto que representan distinas semanas.

Comment: Perdon fue error de copy paste @LuisCazares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si necesitas que en algún lugar el posible valor de un campo que venga vacío se sustituya por otro valor... Necesitarás usar la función ISNULL de SQL SERVER.

El uso sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLA WHERE ISNULL(MI_COLUMNA_NULA, 27) == 27
```

De esta manera, cuando el valor de MI_COLUMNA_NULA sea null, será sustituido el null por un 27.

**Corregido para adaptarlo al orden correcto de las tablas:**

```
select V.IdUser, V.Codigo, sum(V.Cantidad) as Cantidad

FROM (select * from(select IdUser,Codigo,Temporada,SUM(Cantidad) as Cantidad
from SCantidadesP group by IdUser,Cod_Prod,Temporada,Cantidad
) V1 where V1.Cantidad <> 0) V

left join (select max(S.Semana) as Semana, V.IdUser, V.Codigo from SVisitas V
 left join Calendario S ON V.Fecha between S.Inicio and S.Fin 
group by V.IdUser, V.Codigo) A on A.IdUser=V.IdUser and A.Codigo=V.Codigo 

left join (Select * from Calendario where Getdate() between Inicio and Fin
)S on V.Temporada=S.Temporada

WHERE V.Semana between A.Semana and S.Semana 
group by V.IdUser,V.Codigo
```

La página de la documentación:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Te completo la respuesta con un enlace a un blog en el que explica muy claro cómo usar los joins: [como funciona inner left right full join](https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-funciona-inner-left-right-full-join)

**Aquí verás porqué ahora sí debe salir los datos que deseas, y como el A.Semana saldrá null, por lo que deberás usar el ISNULL(A.Semana, 27)**
[image: Aquí verás porqué ahora sí debe salir los datos que deseas, y como el A.Semana saldrá null, por lo que deberás usar el ISNULL(A.Semana, 27)]

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo!

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta ya lo intente de esa manera  no funciona, porque la consulta A no regresa ningún valor, osea no es NULL ni es nada, nose si me entienda

Comment: Vale, lo que sucede es que la tabla A no tiene datos ¿no? Otra pregunta... ¿Porqué no sacas ninguna columna de la tabla A que sea semana?

Comment: esa es la que necesito exactamente :c

Comment: Ya entendí... Necesitas que saque datos aunque la tabla A no devuelva datos... Ok, entonces no puedes usar left join, ahora te comento mejor... Deja que me asegure..

Comment: De la primer consulta arroja un valor semana si los codigos de la tabla SCantidadesP  tambien existen en SVisitas, si no existen ahi debe arrojar el numero 27 para el valor de la columna Semana

Comment: Ya, pero no puedes comparar 2 columnas de subconsultas distintas entre sí. O sea, poder si puedes, pero al usar un left join, estás filtrando todo lo que tiene la tabla A que exista en V, porque el left join, da importancia a los datos de la tabla de la izquierda (tabla A) antes que a la tabla de la derecha (tabla V). ¿Cuál es la tabla que sí o sí tiene todos los datos que han de salir?

Comment: Es la tabla SCantidadesP la que tiene todos los datos que han de salir

Comment: Prueba lo que te pongo ahora en la respuesta, a ver si así va mejor... En teoría, ahora, te mostrará todo lo que esté en V y también saldrán los datos de A, quizás, ahora te salgan datos de A a NULL, quizás, ahora, sí debas usar el ISNULL

Comment: Creo que no probaste el código Rubén, porque ni siquiera compila.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una modificacion en sus tablas

```
SCantidadesP
IdUser int
Codigo varchar(5)
Cantidad int
Semana int  DEFAULT 27    // poner un valor por defecto
Temporada int
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola Huntzberger: Puedes realizarlo de esta manera. Solo te voy a poner, lo que sería el conjunto A, entendiendo que lo que necesitas es que A de todas todas, devuelva un resultado donde su Semana = 27, pero su idUser y su codigo serán un 0.

```
SELECT U2.Semana, U2.IdUser, U2.Codigo FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NUMROWS, orden, Semana,IdUser,Codigo

FROM
(
SELECT 1 AS orden
     , MAX(S.Semana) AS Semana
     , V.IdUser
     , V.Codigo
FROM SVisitas V
     LEFT JOIN Calendario S ON V.Fecha BETWEEN S.Inicio AND S.Fin
       GROUP BY V.IdUser
              , V.Codigo
UNION ALL
SELECT 0
     , 27
     , 0
     , 0
FROM(VALUES(1)) tbl(n)
) AS u
) AS U2
WHERE U2.NUMROWS >1 AND orden > 0
OR U2.NUMROWS= 1 AND orden = 0
```

Basicamente, a la consulta de Svisitas y Calendario, le agregamos una fila que contiene un 27 para la semana.

En la salida de este conjunto llamado u, utilizamos una función de ventana para obtener cuantos registros existen en U.

En la salida de este conjunto llamado u2, filtramos si el numero de filas es > 1 recogemos todos los registros de Svisitas y Calendario porque escogemos, los que tienen la columna orden un 1 y si solo tiene 1 registro, entonces, recogemos el de orden 0 que es el 27.

Por tanto U2 sería tú conjunto A, luego continuaría tu query tal cual.